# PostgreSQL: Partition table by external (non-column) value

Tags: postgresql

I want to split up a table into partitions, where I have a partition for each distinct value of a column. So, if `foo_id` is the column, I want to put a row with `foo_id=23` into the partition `bar_23`. Is it possible to then remove the column from the partitions and still use the value for selecting the partition via constraints or do I have to explicitly name the partition table in the query?

I.e., can I do this

```
INSERT INTO bar (foo_id, other) (23, 'value');
```

without actually having `foo_id` in the table? Or do I have to go the explicit way:

```
INSERT INTO bar_23 (other) ('value');
```

Comment: How would the RDBMS know which partition to use in any given operation? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I guess theoretically you could do something like this with inheriting tables from a main table and inserting into them, but I second Politank-Z's question: why?

Comment: The idea is to not store redundant information. `foo_id` would be the same all over the partition.